# デバッグモードの挙動について

Tags: xcode, xcode12

Xcode側からビルドしてアプリを立ち上げた時と、wait for executable to be launchedを使って手動でアプリを立ち上げた時でUITabBarControllerにtitleが表示されなかったり、他にもいくつか挙動が変わってしまいます。

そもそも、Xcode側から立ち上げる時と手動で立ち上げる時で、どんな違いがあるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「一回アプリを落とした」と言うのは正確には何を表しているのでしょうか？もしホームボタンをダブルタップしたときのアプリ選択画面からスワイプでアプリを強制終了させることを表しているのであれば、その状態から「手動でアプリを立ち上げた時」と「Xcode側からビルドしてアプリを立ち上げた時」とには違いはありません。「いくつか挙動が変わって」しまうと言うのであれば、微妙な実行タイミングの違いなど、本来影響を受けてはいけないような事柄に影響を受けてしまうような脆い実装になっている可能性が高いと思われます。

Comment: kaitoon さんは、質問者の Kaitoon さんと同じ方であろうと推察します。本来は質問内容を編集するか、コメントとして書くべき内容が、アカウントが分かれてしまっているので、それが出来なくなっているのでしょうか。まずは[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を呼んでアカウントの統合を依頼してみてください。ご自身の投稿を編集したり、コメントを書いたりすることができるようになります。